# Transfer Exchange emails and appointments between two win application

Tags: .net, email, outlook, exchange-server

I have two windows application that can view and manage my exchange details. create new appointments/emails and associate them to a case in the system. the application DB stores the exchange details in the table with unique id like the following:

appt uid: 040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000E37B8BD06CEBD001000000000000000010000000F954DB4F5C98A74BABEBDA38AEF334C4

entry id: 00000000E640F9D261714A47A840035DFB436582070065DEEEBF175A394DBABEF812FF6AA9C300000079FD60000065DEEEBF175A394DBABEF812FF6AA9C300003023D0CA0000

location: AAMkADQ5NTc0ZDk3LTE2MDgtNDBlZi04MzA0LTM1ZDYwZjA1MGVhYQBGAAAAAADmQPnSYXFKR6hAA137Q2WCBwBl3u6/F1o5Tbq++BL/aqnDAAAAef1gAABl3u6/F1o5Tbq++BL/aqnDAAAwI9DKAAA=

Any idea what it means and if I can bring new appointments and emails from another win application that uses the same logic?

when I double click an appointment from the application it opens it in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you first use a MAPIEditor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy to look at a few calendar appointments and those I'd should make more sense

appt uid should be GlobalObjectId or the CleanGlobalObjectId

EntryId is PidTagEntryId (PR_EntryId) property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842499.aspx

location: (Just a guess) but it looks like the EWSId of the Calendar Folder you can use the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ to verify that

> > Any idea what it means and if I can bring new appointments and emails from another win application that uses the same logic?

You can open an appointment using the EntryId from the Outlook OOM or you can use EWS to search for the Items based on the appt uid and the Location (EWS Folder). If you look at the code from the other application then it would make much more sense (eg you can see the Folder.Binds,searches or OOM code etc).

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen, I will try it today.